SCD Type2 - Selecting latest row on the change date
I have the following table
CREATE TABLE #CustomerDimension (
    row_id int,
    customer_id INT NOT NULL,
    customer_name VARCHAR(255),
    address VARCHAR(255),
    start_date DATE NOT NULL,
    end_date DATE,
    is_current CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'Y'
);

-- Insert sample data
INSERT INTO #CustomerDimension VALUES (1,101, 'John Doe', '123 Main St',   '2024-01-01', '2024-06-18', 'N')
INSERT INTO #CustomerDimension VALUES (2,101, 'John Doe', '456 Elm St',    '2024-06-18', '2024-06-23', 'N')
INSERT INTO #CustomerDimension VALUES (3,101, 'John Doe', '789 Oak St',    '2024-06-23', '2024-06-24', 'N')
INSERT INTO #CustomerDimension VALUES (4,101, 'John Doe', '987 Pine St',  '2024-06-24', NULL, 'Y')

SELECT * FROM #CustomerDimension;


This is a slowly changing dimension type 2, each time the address changes, a new row is added.
I want to select the latest row as of 2024-06-23, this is the date when the address changed from row_id =2 to row_id =3. But I want to do it in a generic what so that I could track the changes daily. No matter what date I supply, I want to get back the latest row for that day. Essentially where is_current would have been Y.
What I found is that I could write something like:
SELECT * 
FROM #CustomerDimension 
WHERE '2024-06-23' BETWEEN start_date AND COALESCE(end_date, '9999-12-31')

But that would return both rows 2 and 3. Is there a way to just get row 3?

Don't you simply need to select MAX(start_date) WHERE start_date = dateToCheck? Put it in a subquery if you need the entire row for that date

SELECT *
FROM #CustomerDimension
WHERE '2024-06-23' >= start_date AND '2024-06-23' < COALESCE(end_date, '9999-12-31')

Hi - a couple of points 1) Always populate the end date (with 9999-12-31 when is_current =y) so you don’t need to use coalesce. 2) Decide what your date logic actually means - for example on 2024-06-18 is the first record current or the second one - and ensure your SQL reflects this. The way you have your data means you can’t use BETWEEN (as it will return 2 records), my preference is to set the start date of the next record to be one day greater than the end date of the previous record then you don’t have this issue

I don't think that first solution would work since not all dates will be there. For example 2024-06-19 is not in the data, but on that date row_id =2 was the latest row.
The other 2 solutions would work. thanks

tinazmu answer above is correct:
SELECT * FROM #CustomerDimension WHERE '2024-06-23' >= start_date AND '2024-06-23' < COALESCE(end_date, '9999-12-31')
But there are some subtleties.
A date implicitly has a "start of day" time. So when you say the end_date = '2024-06-18', it means the end_date is the start of '2024-06-18'. This fact is a bit ambiguous when you first read it.
I prefer to use datetime2(7) as the start and end dates, which is accurate to 7 decimal points of a second. No ambiguity! In your example, it's not immediately clear which row you would get back if your as-at was a datetime e.g.'2024-06-23 8:30'. It's also far less likely (but not impossible) that someone using BETWEEN will get back multiple rows:
From SQL documentation, "BETWEEN returns TRUE if the value of test_expression is greater than or equal to the value of begin_expression and less than or equal to the value of end_expression."
